# SharePoint 2013 Facebook authentication without ACS

Tags: 2013, claims-based-auth

Since ACS is getting deprecated and in SharePoint 2010, we used to be able to create STS project using visual studio 2010.

I'm trying to achieve the same (Logging in using Facebook) in SharePoint 2010 using Visual Studio 2012/2013.

In Visual Studio 2013, there's Owin/katana authentication which make it very easy for web applications to use OAuth, but how do we use Owin for SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create your own STS. You could try IdentityServer as a base, but it is not trivial.

Another option would be to use something like Auth0 (auth0.com). They support this scenario out of the box.